# LibGDX : Rendering a TextureRegion renders whole texture

Tags: java, opengl-es, libgdx

SO I have a large Texture that is broken up in to 64x64 blocks.

I load this in to LibGDX using

```
texture = new Texture("texturemap.png");
regions = TextureRegion.split(texture, 64, 64);
```

I create a Cube (mesh)

```
modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
cube = modelBuilder.createBox(Constants.cubeSize, Constants.cubeSize, Constants.cubeSize,
                new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.BLUE)),
                VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal | VertexAttributes.Usage.TextureCoordinates);
```

In my Rendering look I want to choose what Texture region to render however it always renders the whole texture

```
Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
Gdx.gl20.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
Gdx.gl20.glCullFace(GL20.GL_BACK);
Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);


shaderProgram.begin();
//texture.bind();
regions[1][5].getTexture().bind();
shaderProgram.setUniformMatrix("u_projTrans", camera.combined);
shaderProgram.setAttributef("a_color", 1, 1, 1, 1);
shaderProgram.setUniformi("u_texture", 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < chunks2.size; i ++ ) {
            chunks2.get(i).render(shaderProgram);
        }

   shaderProgram.end();
```

Am I missing the point to TextureRegions?  It always renders the whole texture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only using the region to get the `Texture` it points to. You are never actually using the `TextureRegion` it self.

A `TextureRegion` defines, well, a region of a texture. For that it refers to a `Texture` as well as the location and size of the region on that texture. For rendering you typically want this location and size to be normalized, also called UV coordinates. You can get those from the `TextureRegion` by using the `getU()` and `getV()` methods for the first corner and the `getU2()` and `getV2()` methods for the other corner. You can get texture, as you already found, using the `getTexture()` method.

There are practically two ways how you can do that:

a) Bake the texture region onto the mesh, practically scaling and moving the UV coordinates of your Mesh. Since you're using [ModelBuilder](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/ModelBuilder%2C-MeshBuilder-and-MeshPartBuilder), you could that using the [`setUVRange`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/utils/MeshPartBuilder.html#setUVRange-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion-) method when creating the part. The `createBox` method you're using is convenience method, that you probably want to avoid using unless you're debugging. Check [it's source](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/1.6.4/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/utils/ModelBuilder.java#L195-L200) to see what it actually does. In your case you could use this instead:

```
modelBuilder.begin();
MeshPartBuilder mpb = modelBuilder.part("box", primitiveType, attributes, material);
mpb.setUVRange(yourRegion);
mpb.box(width, height, depth);
cube = modelBuilder.end();
```

b) Scale the coordinates in your shader. For this you provide the region, in the form of an translation and scaling to your shader as uniforms. Note that this implies that you need a separate render call for each separate region, so if you're using TextureRegions because you've packed your textures in the hope to gain on performance, then this is not the option that you want.

The `DefaultShader` (e.g. used by [`ModelBatch`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/ModelBatch)) supports `TextureRegion` for diffuse textures by default. [Here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/1.6.4/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/g3d/TextureRegion3DTest.java) is an example of that. Since you're using your own shader, you'd have to implement that in that shader. It is typically a one-liner in your vertex shader, e.g.:

```
v_diffuseUV = u_diffuseUVTransform.xy + a_texCoord0 * u_diffuseUVTransform.zw;
```

Where `u_diffuseUVTransform` is a vec4 containing U and V (.xy) and U2-U and V2-V (.zw).

Comment: You sir are a ****ing god!, One day I will buy you beer, cola or something!

Comment: As I am creating lots of meshes and merging them together, I gonna need to think about how I do this.  Solution A is the way I got to go but I need to be able to switch UVRange per mesh (chunk) I could just have a static cube per texture when making the chunks

Comment: It sounds like you're doing premature optimizations here. Packing textures is typically done for *2D* to avoid texture binds. ModelBatch on the other hand can use multiple textures at once, so for *3D* (using modelbatch) it might be just overcomplicating at no gain to pack textures. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/ModelBatch#texturebinder

Comment: I am not actually rendering my mesh in a modelbatch, I am doing it in a ShaderProgram.begin().  What I am trying to achieve (you did warn me I running before walking) is a minecraft type chunking system.  So I create 16*16*16 meshes(its actually a lot less) and then create 1 giant mesh from that as the chunk.  The issue is that the chunk will contain many different textured meshes. so 0,0,0 could be grass, 0,1,0 could be stone

Comment: Start using ModelBatch. Perhaps this helps: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/g3d/ModelCacheTest.java it does the merging for you automatically based on the material, just feed it the cube models and see how it works.